# Why node js Active Directory results in etimedout?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, active-directory

I am using node js express framework. My Active Directory is not connecting and it always results in the following error

> "code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect"

This is my code I have written for accessing the Active Directory:

```
var path = require('path');
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var directoryConfig = { 
    url: 'ldap://'+process.env['USERDNSDOMAIN'], 
    baseDN: 'dc=xxx,dc=yyy,dc=zzz',
    username: process.env['USERPROFILE'].split(path.sep)[2],
    password: 'test'
}
```

And in the get request of index.js page

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ad = new ActiveDirectory(directoryConfig);
    ad.userExists(directoryConfig.username, function(err, exists) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }
        console.log(directoryConfig.username + ' exists: ' + exists);
    });
});
```

I have searched for `etimedout` error but none of the solution is preferable for active directory. Please suggest us a way to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Today I am getting this error:{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"192.zzz.xx.yy","port":389}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only reason for this issue is wrong ldap url. I get clear information from the network administrator and make sure to give correct ldap url which fixes my issue. This link helped me https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/issues/110